# Can this be a generator?

Tags: generator

I have two single-phase motors. This motors working in a fan. When I disconnect it from the mains and rotate it manually it produces 160V-190V.

The problem is when this generator runs manually and totally disconnected from the mains, I connect the two wires to Christmas lights and it lights up.  When I connect it to a 110V-220V appliance, the appliance did not work, the voltage (using a multitester) from the fan drops down and the fan seems to run from the electricity it produces.

I learned this from google and it says it's backfeeding.

Please help me to stop this backfeeding problem from an AC generator.

Electricity is always going back from its source, so I think the backfeeding is because the electrons is going back to the generator is why it is running from the electricity it produce, am I right? (I use this picture to describe the image of the problem in my head.)

[image]

This is the motor. I don't know what type it is.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of your previous question, [Single-Phase Generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531592/single-phase-generator) and the one before it. Please do not post repeats. Instead fix the earlier question and delete this one.

Comment: Sorry. The one I asked before is deleted yet it does not answer my question. I just need an answer or idea a little bit so please bare with me. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting this idea of "backfeeding"?

Comment: @JustineGuhit - Hi, You said: "*The [question] I asked before is deleted*". No, it isn't  deleted - it's [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531592/single-phase-generator) and that is why this question has been closed as a duplicate of that one. If you want to add new information (or improve your question any other way) then, as already commented, the Stack Exchange philosophy is that you should *edit the original question* - not repost a slightly different version of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generators are current sources. the strength of the magnets strictly limits the amount of current available.

If your appliance wants more current than the generator can provide the voltage will drop.

Comment: Then why the generator suddenly get shock when I turn on the appliance ? I only get the idea of it getting backfeed and i need to stop that. How will I do it ?

Comment: what's backfeed?

Comment: if you put an electrical load on a generator it will put a mechanical load on the thing that's turning it.

Comment: So it means that I need to put more force to the generator ?

Comment: yes it would mean that.